# Difference between using os.system and snakemake.shell

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm fairly new to snakemake, so I still struggle with combining shell commands and python code.

My solution is to make script files and then perform the shell command within this script.

Is there any mechanical difference between envoking `snakemake.shell` and `os.system` for executing command lines?

Example:

```
sample = ["SRR12845350"]
rule prefetch:
  input:
    "results/Metadata/{sample}.json"
  output:
    "results/SRA/{sample}.sra
  params:
    "prefetch %s -o %s"
  script:
    "scripts/prefetch.py"
```

And `prefetch.py`is:

```
from json import load
from snakemake import shell
from os import system

json_file = snakemake.input[0]
prefetch  = snakemake.params[0]
sra_file  = snakemake.output[0]

json    = load(open(json_file))
sra_run = json["RUN_accession"]

shell(prefetch %(sra_run, sra_file))  # option 1
system(prefetch %(sra_run, sra_file))  # option 2
```

Comment: some self-advertisement: I made a pipeline based on snakemake that, among lots of things, can download samples from SRA/GEO/ENA/DDBJ for you. Take a look, it might do the things you want, and otherwise might help you tackle future problems: [seq2science](https://vanheeringen-lab.github.io/seq2science/)

Comment: `os.system()` generally should not be used in new code at all unless you understand _exactly_ how it works; it's very easy to unintentionally create security vulnerabilities when using it. In general (absent anything snakemake-specific), `subprocess.Popen`, `subprocess.run`, etc. should be used instead.

Comment: ...for example, if you run `os.system(f"prefetch results/Metadata/{sample}.json -o results/SRA/{sample}.sra")`, you're going to have a very bad day if your code is passed a `sample` value that contains `$(rm -rf ~)`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the rm -rf ~ though ... is very scary! Thank you so much for the warning!!!
So when inspecting the github snakemake.shell command referenced in @Maarten-vd-Sande 's answer, Popen is used to execute the code. Does this mean that the `rm -rf ...` arguments could be avoided?

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande self-advertising aside - your tool look extremely useful for general bioinformatics analysis - I'll definitely see if I can get some inspiration on Snakemake setup from that, and will bookmark this for future use!

Comment: @Kasper, it depends on whether `shell=True` is used. If it's off -- as by default -- command substitutions like `$(...)` will not be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell` is just a helper function to make it easier to call command-line arguments from snakemake. Learning snakemake can be overwhelming, and learning the fine intricacies of Python's `os.system` and `subprocess` is unnecessarily complicating. The snakemake `shell` command does a couple sanity checks, sets some environment variables e.g. the number of threads the command can use and some other "small" stuff, but [under the hood](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/4a63a26959cd0626e2113e48b4d4fe5a5421d954/snakemake/shell.py#L172-L181) just calls `subprocess.Popen` on your command. Both options should work, but since you are writing a snakemake wrapper, it's probably slightly better to use shell as it is designed to be used in snakemake.